# C# Converting List to Enumerable and Selecting With LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have a question related to an Enumerable and list of integers. I have the below code that is throwing an error stating "'int' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and has some invalid arguments." I'm sure this is something easy, but was wondering if anyone could help out. Thanks!

```
public static IList<Site> GetSiteFromSites(DataTable data)
{
    var linqRegions = Enumerable.Empty<int>();

    IList<Site> sites = data.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>
    {
        return new Site()
        {
            id = r.Field<string>("id"),
            name = r.Field<string>("name"),
            address_line1 = r.Field<string>("address_line1"),
            address_line2 = r.Field<string>("address_line2"),
            post_code = r.Field<string>("post_code"),
            county = r.Field<string>("county"),
            city = r.Field<string>("city"),
            phone_number = r.Field<string>("phone_number"),                                
            regions = linqRegions.Where(u => u.Field<int>("regions") == r.Field<int>("regions")).ToList().Select(z => z.Field<int>("regions")).ToList()      
            //error is thrown for above line of code "regions"               
        };
    }).ToList();

    return sites;
}
```

Comment: Well, `linqRegions` is an `IEnumerable<int>`, yet you're calling `u.Field` on it's items. `u` is an `int`, and the compiler is telling you that there is no method or property called `Field` for an `int`.

Comment: Also, you never populate `linqRegions` with anything. What are you trying to compare in the `Where` clause in the line that does the `regions` assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `linqRegions` is an empty enumerable of ints.

In the line where the error is thrown, you are calling the Where() method where you try to get the `Field` property of each element. Because each element is an int, it throws the `'int' does not contain a definition for 'Field'` error.

Change your line with the error to this:

```
regions = linqRegions.Where(u => u == r.Field<int>("regions")).ToList()
```

This will always return zero elements (because `linqRegions` is empty), so don't forget to populate it. And even then, the line doesn't make any sense because it will always return a list of the same values (values equal to `r.Field<int>("regions")`).

Comment: Thank you. So the empty value is still an error. There is an underlying stored procedure running and this method is basically mapping all of the columns. However, that columns requires the data type of an array, or list. I don't want to pass the data in as a separate argument bc it is actually just a hardcoded value in the sql query (for now).  Does that make sense? Is there a way to do this by removing linqLocations? I appreciate the response. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you any further. I have no idea what you are talking about because I have no real context here about your situation.